# Alternatie proof that the set of finite subsets of the natural numbers is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am learning analysis using the textbook *Understnading Analysis* and came across this  problem:

Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set.

I have seen several proofs of this fact, but came up with a one I haven't seen mentioned before, but I'm suspect if it's correct. Here is my proof:

Call the set under investigation $\mathcal{A}$

Define $$A_i = \left\{ S \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid S \text{ is finite and } \min(S) = i \right\}$$

Since each $S \in \mathcal{A}$ is finite, this definition is well defined, i.e. the minimum always exists.

From the well-orderliness of the natural numbers, we get that

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} = \mathcal{A}$

Now, a countably infinite union of countable sets is countable (notice that since the indices for the minimums are natural numbers, this is indeed a countable union). So all that is needed is to show that each $A_{i}$ is countable.

To show that $A_{i}$ is countable, we consider $\bigcup_{S\in A_{i}} S$. This is a union of finite subsets of the natural numbers, and so has a well defined maximum. Let $s = \max(\bigcup_{S\in A_{i}} S)$.

Notice that then $$A_{i} \subseteq \mathcal{P}( \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : i\leq n \leq s \right\})$$

But then it must be that $A_{i}$ is countable, since $\mathcal{P}( \left\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : i\leq n \leq s \right\})$ is countable.

This completes my proof.

Comment: 1. You don't need to use limit notation here, it's fine to just write the infinite union $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ directly. 2. For this argument to make sense you need to have written $\text{max}(S) = i$ in your definition. Then it's clear that each $A_i$ is finite. If you'd have written $\text{max}(S) \le i$ then it would even have been clear that $|A_i| = 2^i$.